# Vertical scrollbar in listbox

Tags: php, css, yii, listbox

How do I add a scrollbar to my listbox? Here is an example of my code below:

```html
<?php echo $form->listBox($model,'categories', 
  CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(
      'campaign_id='.$model->post_id), 
      'blog_id', 'blog_name'), 
    array('id' => 's1', 'multiple' => 'multiple')
); ?>
```

I have already tried using overflow: auto but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

putting the styling in the array seemed to do the trick

```html
<?php echo $form->listBox($model,'categories', 
  CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(
      'campaign_id='.$model->post_id), 
      'blog_id', 'blog_name'), 
    array('id' => 's1', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'style'=>'width:auto; height:166px; overflow:auto')
); ?>
```